# Session 'app': Install failed. Installation failed. Rerun. On Android studio

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

I am using real device for debugging since virtual device is not supported in my PC. Adb is detecting my device but when I run an app, it's giving the above error.

Can anyone help me resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

It is either there is no space on your android phone. so free up space Or your android API version does not support instant run, so go to settings and uncheck instant run.

Comment: "It is either there is no space on your android phone [...]" or?